# Separate output when results='hold' in knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way to separate or section the output in a `{r results='hold'}` block in `knitr` without needing to manually insert a `print('--------')` command in between or the like? I want to avoid such extra `print` lines is that it makes the code much harder to read.

For example, you need to be quite trained to see where the output from one line stops and the next begins in the output from this:

````
```{r, results='hold'}
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris))
#print('-------------')  # Not a solution
summary(aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris))
```
````

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6880 -0.3285 -0.0060  0.3120  1.3120 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         5.0060     0.0728  68.762  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030   9.033 8.77e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030  15.366  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5148 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6187,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6135 
F-statistic: 119.3 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Maybe some knitr option or a more general R printing option?

Comment: Is `use two code chunk` an option?

Comment: @TCZhang, that would split up the code. I want to keep the code in one chunk but mark in the output when it is generated by a new line in the chunk.